# YML формат. Как реализовать фасовку?

Tags: php, yml, яндекс-маркет

Дело в том, что в моём магазине можно купить как 200г, как 500, так и весь килограмм. Возможно ли это записать в YML формат? Чтобы для offer`а прям прописать все возможные фасовки с ценами.
Или возможно сделать только через параметры? :

```
<param name="Вес">200 г</param>
```

И с group_id объединяющем товары с разной фасовкой?
Я бы принял такой случай, но YML требует уникальных **offer id**. А в данной ситуации выходит, что один товар мы пишем, к примеру, 3 раза (200г,500г,1000г) с одинаковым **offer group_id** и различным **param**
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то расскажет о более разумном способе, либо поведает как лучше реализовать в таком случаи уникальный **offer id**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [описания YML](https://help.yandex.ru/partnermarket/offers.xml):

> Каждое товарное предложение описывается отдельным элементом

Соответственно у вас на каждую фасовку отдельный offer со своей ценой.

По поводу генерации уникального ID опять же смотрим описание:

> В атрибуте id указывается идентификатор товарного предложения. Атрибут
>   может содержать только цифры и латинские буквы.

Я не знаю, как у вас устроена привязка фасовки к товару, но мой вариант такой: offerID  = ID товара + буква латинского алфавита. По индексу буквы в алфавите можно определить индекс фасовки среди всех фасовок данного товара. Здесь важно, чтобы порядок фасовок при генерации YML и при получении заказа от Маркета был один и тот же.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сделаю добавлением латинских букв!